# Optimal settings to capture firework at night using Nikon D3200 with 18mm - 105mm Zoom Lens?

Tags: night, manual-focus, overexposure, fireworks, nikon-d3200

I tried take photos of firework using my Nikon D3200 with 18mm - 105mm Zoom Lens in Aperture Mode. But I cannot get a good focus since if happens in sky at different heights. This made most of my shot blurred. Also, Need to know the optimal camera settings to get maximum shutter speed at night which can give best quality photo of firework. Thank you.

Comment: See: [What settings should I be using to photograph fireworks?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/what-settings-should-i-be-using-to-photograph-fireworks). If after reading that question, you have a further question, I would suggest editing this one to note that.

Comment: thank you. I found this: http://www.creativelive.com/courses/photographing-fireworks

I found a video very helpful. I'll shoot out next question after i do experiment soon.